# Using loc on two columns to perform calculations that replace values of another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have been stuck on this way too long. All I am trying to do is create a new column called `Duration Target Date` which derives from `Standard Duration Days` + `Date/Time Created`. Below is my code so far:
From my POV, I think that this code will iterate from 0 to the length of the data frame. If there is "No Set Standard Duration" in the `Standard Duration Days` column then goes to my else statement and overwrites that given cell with blank(same as I initialized it). However, if the code realizes that there is anything but "No Set Standard Duration" it should then add the value from the given cell from column `Standard Duration Days` with column `Date/Time Created`. I want the new value to be in the new column `Duration Target Date` at the corresponding index.

```
newDF["Duration Target Date"] = ""

for i in range(0,len(newDF)):
    if newDF.loc[i,"Standard Duration Days"] != "No Set Standard Duration":
        newDF.loc[i,"Duration Target Date"] = (timedelta(days = int(newDF.loc[i,"Standard Duration Days"])) + newDF.loc[i,"Date/Time Created"])
    else:
        newDF.loc[i,"Duration Target Date"] == ""
```

I noticed that this works partially but then it eventually stops working... I also get an error when I run this: "KeyError 326"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add the columns and leave the `NaT` (Not a Time) error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Standard Duration Days": [3, 5, "No Set Standard Duration"],
    "Date/Time Created": ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01']
})

# 1. Convert string dates to pandas timestamps.
df['Date/Time Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time Created'])

# 2. Create time deltas, coercing errors.
delta = pd.to_timedelta(df['Standard Duration Days'], unit='D', errors='coerce')

# 3. Create new column by adding delta to 'Date/Time Created'.
df['Duration Target Date'] = (df['Date/Time Created'] + delta).dt.normalize()

>>> df
     Standard Duration Days Date/Time Created Duration Target Date
0                         3        2019-01-01           2019-01-04
1                         5        2019-02-01           2019-02-06
2  No Set Standard Duration        2019-03-01                  NaT
```

Adding text to a numeric column converts the entire column to `object` which takes more memory and is less efficient.  Generally, one wants to leave empty values as `np.nan` or possibly a sentinel value in the case of integers.  Only for display purposes do those get converted, e.g. `df['Duration Target Date'].fillna('')`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues here. First, it looks like you're confusing `loc` with `iloc`. Very easy to do. `loc` looks up by the actual index, which may or may not be the integer-position index. But your `i in range (0, len(newDF))` is iterating by integer-position index. So you're getting your `KeyError 326` because you're getting to the 326th row of your dataframe, but it's index is not actually 326. you can check this by looking at `print(newDF.iloc[320:330])`.

Second and more important issue: you almost never want to iterate through rows in a pandas dataframe. Instead, use a vectorized function that applies to a full column at a time. For your case where you want conditional assignment, the relevant function is `np.where`:

```
boolean_filter = newDF.loc[:,"Standard Duration Days"] != "No Set Standard Duration"
value_where_true = (timedelta(days = newDF.loc[:,"Standard Duration Days"].astype('int'))) + newDF.loc[:,"Date/Time Created"])
value_where_false = ""

newDF["Duration Target Date"] = np.where(boolean_filter, value_where_true, value_where_false)
```

Comment: When I run this, I am getting  KeyError "Standard Duration Days". Any reason on why I might be getting that?

Comment: think my update to the syntax should have fixed it. try again?

Comment: I reran it and now I received the ValueError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'No Set Standard Duration'"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) row-wise:

```
newDF['Standard Duration Days'] = newDF['Standard Duration Days'].astype(int)

newDF['Duration Target Date'] = (newDF
                                .apply(lambda x:, x["Standard Duration Days"] + x["Date/Time Created"] if x["Standard Duration Days"] != "No Set Standard Duration" else None,axis=1)
```

*Note:* Since you haven't provided any data, it is not tested.